# Can repeated exposure to bee venom induce some allergy or worsen actual ones?

Tags: venom

Are there any scientific studies bringing answers to question if repeated exposure to bee venom ca induce some allergy or worsen actual ones?

How about health of long time beekeepers?

Comment: Welcome to HealthSE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. Help us help you. What have you researched on this so far? You may improve your question to comply with site guidelines and make it clearer with an [edit] and the help of [ask]. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know of any specific studies but I have heard of microdosing actually desensitizing the cells involved in allergies and that you can actually start with a tiny dose and gradually increase it until you are t a regular dose and don't have a reaction and the allergy will actually be cured. As for inducing an allergy or worsening actual ones, yes indeed it can. There have been lots of cases and with more than just bee stings of people having a mild allergy with the first exposure and then getting anaphylaxis with the second exposure.